# Hello World Assembly Illegal instruction: 4

Tags: assembly

I am new to assembly and I am trying to get this hello world program to work:

```
.data
msg:
    .ascii  "Hello, world!\n"
    len = . - msg
.text
    .globl start
start:
    movl $len,%edx
    movl $msg,%ecx
    movl $1,%ebx
    movl $4,%eax
    int $0x80
    movl $0,%ebx
    movl $1,%eax
    int $0x80
```

I compile it on mac with:

```
as -o program.o program.s
```

And then link it with:

```
ld -o program program.o
```

Both work perfectly, but when I run the generated program I get the error:

```
Illegal instruction: 4
```

Could someone please tell me how to fix this.

Comment: How could I write a hello world on mac then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Mac equivalent of your code is something like:

```
.data
msg:
    .ascii "Hello, world!\n"
    len = . - msg
.text
    .globl start
start:
    movq $len, %rdx
    lea msg(%rip), %rsi
    movq $1,%rdi
    movq $0x2000004,%rax
    syscall
    movq $0,%rdi
    movq $0x2000001,%rax
    syscall
```

Notice that the sys call convention is different (different registers, parameters and calling mechanism), and I've changed it to 64-bit.